# Upload project as zip file to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to upload a project folder as a zip file to Visual Studio Team Services repository?

I'm aware of the Team Services features in Visual Studio but I'm having problems with my VS after installing some updates.

Comment: Which source control provider are you using? Do you already have the project in VS Team Services, or are you trying to add a new project? I'm not aware of anything specifically, but I did notice they added some new add folder and create file features in the code explorer online. You might be able to add something file-at-a-time as long as it's text.

Comment: I'm using tfs and I'm trying to add it as a new project. I see the add files option but that doesn't seem like it's for uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot upload the project as zip file to VSTS directly.

There is an "Add file(s)" option that allow you to upload the existing items.
[image]

You can drag and drop multiple files into it to upload the files. But since you cannot drop the folder into it, you can install [Folder Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.FolderManagement) to create the folder structure first and then upload your files.

And you can also use [tf command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.100).aspx) to create work space and check in files.